# Using lib files in Android Studio to android/app/src/main/java/(sampleproject)/MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity

I want to test that the firebase is connected to the application but the lib files are not loaded in the android folder

I have a project made using flutter in AS and i can run it in simulator but now i connected it to the firebase and wanted to use it in my phone device but i realized that it needed the java/(sampleproject)/MainActivity. So i also tested a new project using only the android part with the MainActivity, xml, and all and the template ran in the phone. i am confused how to run/import/use the files from lib to android

EDIT:
I tried using an emulator (I didn't before since it was so laggy) but the same error keeps appearing even I have the file

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
package identifier or launch activity not found.
Please check C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\maxilom_ustp_ios\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml for errors.
No application found for TargetPlatform.android_x64.
Is your project missing an android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml?
Consider running "flutter create ." to create one.